# How to solve this Green's theorem Question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative, greens-theorem

I have been given the question by my university as an Assignment to solve. I have solved but when I shared with my fellows they are saying the answer of this question is zero, but I am getting the other answer. I have tried all the ways, I am so confused that how the answer is zero? Kindly anyone help me in this.

**QUESTION:**
[image: question]

**MY TRY:**

[image: answer1]
[image: answer2]
[image: answer3]
[image: answer4]

Kindly anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) wrong.
$$\oint_{C}(Ldx+Mdy)=\iint_{D}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)dxdy$$

$$\oint_{C}(2xydx+x^2dy)=\iint_{D}\left(2x-2x\right)dxdy=\iint_{D}0dxdy=0$$

Comment: are you sure is it true? I mean I already realized that I wrote the formula wrong. But do not we have to go through the process of integration instead of just canceling them out and making it zero?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar The cancellation is valid since $2x-2x=0$ for all $x$ and the integral becomes $0$ since you you can pull out a constant from the integral and you get $0\cdot$(Integral), which is $0$.

Comment: thank you buddy :) and yeah I know that the cancellation is valid, but I was still asking to be confirmed that if we still need to do the process of Integration or not. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar No problem :)

Comment: There is a theorem that **says** that if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ then the integral around any closed path is 0. That s because, in such a case, there exist F(x,y) such that $dF= P(x,y)dx+ Q(x,y)dy$.   In this case, you can see that by writing $2xydx+ x^2dy= d(x^2y)$ so that the *anti-derivative* is $F(x,y)= x^2y$.  Choose any point on the path as the mutual "starting point" and "ending point".  That anti-derivative, evaluated at the "starting point" and "ending point" will give the same thing so subtracting gives 0.

Answer (score 1):

At one point you say, $\oint_C Pdx+ Qdy= -\int_R\int\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)dxdy$ is the same as $\oint_C Pdx+ Qdy= \int_R\int\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)dxdy$. I don't know where you got that.  At first I thought you were just taking that outside negative into the integral but if you were doing that it would be $\int_R\int\left(-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right) dxdy= \int_R\int\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy$

Comment: Thank you, yeah I realized this mistake. But do we just cancel out the `Pdx` and `Qdy` as they are same or do we still need to go through the whole process of Integration?